# Since createClient has been deprecated, how to create a DB using Node.js now

Tags: node.js

Earlier this was the code to create a database using Node.js:

```
var client = http.createClient(5984, "127.0.0.1")
var request = client.request("PUT", "/johnTest");
request.end();
request.on("response", function(response) {
    response.on("end", function() {
        if ( response.statusCode == 201 ) {
            console.log("Database successfully created.");
        } else {
            console.log("Could not create database.");
        }
    });
});
```

Now since createClient has been deprecated, how do we create a DB using Node.js

Comment: what kind of Database? CouchDB ?

Comment: @Phoenix: Yes.. Sorry I guess the port number is wrong

Comment: the default port number is `5984` but don't rely on http module there are modules like https://github.com/dscape/nano which make this simpler

Comment: @Phoenix I have gone thorough nano module and it works fine, just for the sake of learning wanted to know how to do it with http module since createClient does not work anymore.. \

Comment: there is `http.request`

Comment: @kapilchhattani The docs explicitly say `This function is deprecated; please use http.request() instead`

Comment: @loganfsmyth Is that all I have to change, I thought the declarations would also have been changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var client = http.createClient(5984 /* port */, "127.0.0.1" /* host */)
var request = client.request("PUT" /* method */, "/johnTest" /* path */);
```

would be converted to:

```
var request = http.request({
    port: 5984,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    method: 'PUT',
    path: '/johnTest'
});
```

Also, note, the way you are waiting for the response `'end'` event will work in node `v0.8.x`, but will not fire in `v0.10.x`. I assume since you posted this code that is does actually work though, so you are on `v0.8.x`. If that is not the case, let me know.